# Доступ к состоянию objectManager из пользовательского шаблона балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Задал состояние `objectManager.state.set('selectedId', objectId)`

Стандартное состояние 'activeObject' есть вроде только у кластеров, так?

Как можно достучаться до 'selectedId' из шаблона `BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменять данные для открытого балуна

```
var objectData = objectManager.objects.getById(1);
var extendedProperties = ymaps.util.extend({}, objectData.properties, {selectedId: '123'});
var newData = ymaps.util.extend({}, objectManager.objects.getById(1), {properties: extendedProperties});

objectManager.objects.balloon.open(1).then(function () {
    objectManager.objects.balloon.setData(newData);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tysc2gz5/

Comment: Спасибо, но мне хотелось бы внутри шаблона балуна иметь доступ к общим для всех меток данным. Чтобы и при открытии балуна через стандартные методы, в том числе для кластеров, просто по клику на метке, понимать у какой метки какой статус. Так получается нужно отлавливать все возможные варианты открытия и добавлять в них данные.

Comment: тогда можно зашить ссылку на ObjectManager в шаблон через замыкание